# Android Multiple Language Support - XLIFF

Tags: android, xml, xliff

[XLIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF) is industry standard for sharing or exchanging data for translation. It is an XML file created on standard specification. It looks like Android does not support importing them. Is there a way that XLIFF file can be used in Android? or some way to transform XLIFF into XML?